# Return component message for 5 seconds and then redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, use-state

I am wanting to implement the case where if I navigate to my URL with incorrect query parameters, a message is displayed and then I redirect to another page.

Imagine trying to navigate to a page only a logged in user can see when you're not logged in. I want it to render something like, 'You need to be logged in to see this content' and then after 2 - 5 seconds the page redirects to the `/login` page.

***Note:** Some of the code included is just pseudo-code.*

I know that I can display either the logged in page or redirect with a simple Ternary

```
return hasQueryParams ? <MyLoggedInPage /> : <Redirect to={`/login`} />
```

however, I can't seem to get a `setTimeout` working to delay the redirect...

```
const redirect = () => {
        let redirect = false;

        setTimeout(() => {
            redirect = true;
        }, 5000);

        return redirect
            ? <Redirect to={`/login`} />
            : <h1>Need to be logged in for that</h1>;
    }

return redirect();
```

For this, I am getting an error: `Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it`.

I also tried using `useState`:

```
const [redirectNow, setRedirectNow] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    // Some code unrelated to the timeout/redirect
}, []);

const redirect = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setRedirectNow(false);
        }, 5000);

        return redirectNow
            ? <Redirect to={`/login`} />
            : <h1>Need to be logged in for that</h1>;
    }

return redirect();
```

but this also gets a different error: `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3`

I understand from reading further that we cannot access the `useState` stuff from inside an event handler.

### Update

I should also add that I am already using `useEffect` for other things at this point.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a state to keep the track whether to redirect or not.
2. Update the state after the interval.
3. Redirect upon updating the state.

```
function RedirectComponent() {
  const [shouldRedirect, setShouldRedirect] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      setShouldRedirect(true);
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  }, []);

  if (shouldRedirect) return <Redirect to="/login" />

  return <h1>This is the message</h1>
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I am still getting the same error showing up that I noted when I attempted to set the state from within a timeout before...
I forgot to mention that I am already using `useEffect`, so just wondering if this might be causing an issue.

Comment: The problem is not probably from this component. Could you create a reproducible issue?

Comment: Not without giving away trade secrets ;-)

Comment: You should isolate the instance of the issue and create a minimal reproducible issue. The problem probably lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `custom hook`.

In this case, `useSetTimeout` would work.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function useSetTimeout(timeoutCallback, seconds) {
    const timeoutId = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        timeoutId.current = setTimeout(timeoutCallback, seconds);
        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId.current);
    }, [])
}

function YourComponent(){
  const [redirectNow, setRedirectNow] = useState(false);
  useSetTimeout(()=>{
    setRedirectNow(true);
  }, 5000);
  return redirectNow ? <Redirect to={`/login`} /> : <h1>Need to be logged in for that</h1>;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't seem to like this either. I think the issue is that react doesn't want you to call `setState` from within the `useEffect`....
I do already have my own `useEffect` in place, but commenting out mine in favour of yours still gets the same error :-/

Comment: @physicsboy You can use `useEffect` multiple times in your place.

Comment: I thought that was the case, but some reason I can't get it working.